# Chrome extension upgrade/downgrade version

Tags: windows, installation, google-chrome-extension

When I am trying to upgrade/downgrade to another version of my extension. its look like the version number is being changed. but, the files (java script and images doesn't change) and the directory name doesn't change.

Can some one help please,
Ben :)

Comment: Can you describe your process of upgrading?

Comment: Maybe Chrome is caching the extension's files? Try restarting Chrome between installations.

Answer (score 0):

It was am issue of having version 0.0.0 on the computer. This is make all things wrong.
otherwise it works.